# Docker Build COPY/ADD preserve Owner/Group

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I would like to copy all files from a folder in my docker build context. The files in the folder are mixed with different owners and groups (e.g. UID=400 GUID=800 etc.), which I need to preserve (I also need to preserve timestamps, etc.)

So basically I need a 1:1 copy of the files to my docker image.

When I use ADD/COPY, it doesn't preserve any the owner/group IDs which is also stated in the documentation. (defaults to 0)

I have made a workaround which uses rsync (-a) with localhost, but it's not an ideal solution.
I could also use the docker cp command and commit the image but I would like to use this in my dockerfile.

Is there any way to do this?
(Docker Version 20.10.16-r2)

Edit:
I have also tried

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=myfiles,target=/myfiles cp -ar /myfiles/* /container_target/
```

but this doesn't preserve owner, etc. neither

EDIT:
I am using `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`

Comment: soooo use `COPY`?

Comment: `COPY` does not preserve owner:group

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
COPY --chown=docker:docker source /path/to/destination
```

Adjust to your problem,let us know if it does not work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The UID:GUID is still set to 0

Comment: @Ben Then might have found a bug, because the documentation clearly states that this is the way to set ownership of the copied files. It even states that the COPY-operation fails if the names can not be looked up in the container `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

Comment: @SebDieBln I see... The user docker is neither present on my host nor in the container. It may be a fallback? I also use DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 Will try it without the extended build kit

Comment: @SebDieBln It's not only a DOCKER_BUILDKIT issue. It doesn't preserve UID:GID in the legacy build either.

Comment: Remember to "Adjust to your problem", i.e. don't use `--chown=docker:docker` but `--chown=400:800`.

Comment: @SebDieBln I have multiple files MIXED with different UID:GID in different sub-directories. I don't want to COPY each file with their respective Owner/Group as there are literally hundreds of those files and folders. Preserving the original Owner/Group of those files on the host should be available in general. Still, I see that the chown parameter is broken or wrongly documented cause I can use any username/groupname without failing the build

Comment: I don't think you can solve your problem with docker. You can consider creating a `tar` archive which includes the owner, copying that to the container and unpacking it there keeping the archived owner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249833/discussion-between-ben-and-sebdiebln).

Answer (score 1):

You can tar all the files up in a tar-ball and then use

```
ADD tarball.tar.gz .
```

in your Dockerfile. Docker will automatically extract the files from the tar-ball and it'll preserve the original file owner ids.

Comment: I have thought about this as well and it seems to be only valid solution for my case - until docker will consider the preservation and/or fix the issues